# Is there a possibility to add custom spring boot metrics tags at runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics

I'm using Spring Boot with micrometer-registry-prometheus, trying to store custom tags from http headers, security context, etc.

So I found MeterFilter iterface and tried to use it to store the data I need.

But MeterFilter method works after request is completed, so at that point I don't have any information about request.

Seems like the case is pretty common, is there any possibility to achieve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Spring MVC you can define a bean that implements `WebMvcTagsProvider` to take complete control over the tags that are added to metrics for request-response exchanges. Alternatively, you can define a bean that implements `WebMvcTagsContributor` to add to the default tags. Similarly, if you're using Spring WebFlux you can define beans that implements `WebFluxTagsProvider` and `WebFluxTagsContributor` to take complete control over the tags and contribute additional tags respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll check